How to apply caching in data read from database models in amplify gen 2?
Is possible to obtain cache like dynamodb dax or to use some redis using just only amplify gen 2 or maybe is necessary to use custom resources ?. My main focus is the costs regardind to reads about dynamodb table. Please if someone has experiencie about of this i attentive. Thanks!

Is it possible?, yes. But be aware of the reasons you are doing it. Let me explain:
Amplify (Gen 1 and 2) uses App Sync to create the GraphQL API, and this service has a caching feature. See AppSync caching docs. On Amplify Gen2, you can do this by adding something like this on your backend.ts
import { defineBackend } from '@aws-amplify/backend';
import { auth } from './auth/resource';
import { data } from './data/resource';
import { aws_appsync as appsync } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

const backend = defineBackend({
  auth,
  data
});

const appSyncApi = backend.data.resources.graphqlApi;

const cfnApiCache = new appsync.CfnApiCache(appSyncApi.stack, 'MyCfnApiCache', {
  apiCachingBehavior: 'FULL_REQUEST_CACHING',
  apiId: appSyncApi.apiId,
  ttl: 300,
  type: 'SMALL',

  // the properties below are optional
  atRestEncryptionEnabled: false,
  healthMetricsConfig: 'DISABLED',
  transitEncryptionEnabled: false,
});

This will add caching to your API calls, and depending on the TTL, save your backends some requests.
Dynamo is already fast and cheap for small applications, depending on your expected throughput it might be more affordable to not add caching and keep the pricing model on-demand. If you are having performance issues, check your data modeling first and make sure you are avoiding data scans.
Side note: Think about using DAX only for ultra-low latency applications (< 1ms) queries. For most applications, DAX is an overkill.
Hope this helps
